# Solving an inequality involving a function whose input is vectors

Tags: r

Apologies if this question is seemingly abstract. I have made great efforts to present it in a clear light.

Let `S(n,L)` be the set of vectors with entries in `{0,1,2,...,n}` of length `L` e.g. `S(1,2) = {0,0|0,1|1,0|1,1}` and `S(5,1) = {0|1|2|3|4|5}`.

I have a function `F` which takes elements in `S(n,L)` and outputs a real number between 0 and 100.

I want to know, given a real number `r` between 0 and 100, how I could determine the following set for 'reasonably small' `n` and `l`:

`S'(n,L,r) = {v in S(n,L)| F(v) >= r}`

All I have been able to do so far is generate `S(n,L)` via the following code:

```
f = function(n,L){

h = rep(list(0:n),L)

do.call(expand.grid,h)}
```

I am very new to this kind of stuff in R so any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

EDIT: `l` has been changed to `L` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: It appears that you want the subset of `S(n,l)` for which `F( S(n, l))` is greater than `r`. It is unfortunate that you picked the lowercase_L as your variable name because it appears so similar to numeral-1. And you really should change the name of the question. You are not "solving an inequality".

Comment: @Arun: `F` is a function that I have written. `{v in S(n,L)| F(v) >= r}` is mathematical notation and reads 'give me vectors in `S(n,L)`  such that (`|`) when inputted into `F` they yield a number greater than or equal to `r`. I decided to denote this set by `S'(n,L,r)`.

Comment: @DWin: I agree the notation I have used is not ideal. I will edit it now. I believe however that I am solving an inequality: I have the inequality `F(x) >= r` and I want to know which vectors from the set `S(n,L)` satisfy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
# Test values
n<-6
l<-3
r<-0

S.n.l<-f(n,l) # Generate the series
F<-function(x) rnorm(1) # Your function is more complicated
S.n.l [apply(S.n.l,1,F) >= r,] # Check if any value exceeds r and return.
```

But if `F` is vectorized then you won't need `apply`, and your function will be much faster. For example if `F` simply summed the values, then you could calculate all of `F(S.n.l)` at once.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you're describing is called the permutations of your set. In R, use `foo<- 0:n` to create the source vector.    `expand.grid` is fine -- tho' there may be some tools in the `plyr` package which will execute faster.

On the other hand, what your function `F` actually does with these values does matter.  If you just happen to need some random permutation,  then  `sample` will give you a randomly selected permutation each time it's called, w/o needing to create the entire set every time.  If you need to execute `F` for every possible permutation (presumably only once!), then you're still probably better off looping thru the permutations instead of creating a relatively large data object.